# getimagesize very slow on remote image

Tags: php

Good day,

I have a question here. I am trying to fetch image from few external sites as i'm trying to develop link sharing website for my project.

Right now i'm stuck at this part,

```
getimagesize
```

It took basically > 100 seconds to get width and height of remote images. Is there any alternative method to reduce the time?

I tried sites like digg, facebook, image from external site appear very fast. How do they achieve it with any examples?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a open source library to get remote image sizes https://github.com/MatejB/rim

Comment: In all real world examples it is only marginally faster than getimagesize(), though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its depend on server of each site , how fast they are responding your request.  Everything runs at least as fast on the VPS as it does on the shared account, except for getimagesize() which is vastly slower.
Here is quick solution 
1. get file on your server using file_get_contents or curl for temporary purpose.
2. get dimension getimagesize
3. delete the file
alternative
else you can also find some api , where you can submit link or image , they will give info + thumbnails. Info is actually what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Getimagesize downloads the whole file before it evaluates its contents. It's a better idea to use some kind of script which will get a few thousand bytes from the given file and get the width/height from the JPEG/GIF etc. headers.

Check the comments at this url:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php